# Can you open Google Play Movies (not store) to a specific movie from a website(in chrome)?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I am working on a web app to catalog a users movies and ideally would open them in the google play movie app. The current issue I am running into is with Movies Anywhere titles.

Through trial and error, I have figured out how to open a specific movie from the browser in the Play Store.

For example:
https://play.google.com/store/movies/details?id=IkrfpsjTJzo

What I am trying to do is open the Google Play Movies and TV app on android using  an intent.  I am not an android developer, so while I am doing my best to figure it out, I have hit a wall.

This is what I have tried:

```
<a href="intent://open?id=IkrfpsjTJzo#Intent;package=com.google.android.videos;">Watch on Google Play Movies</a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Movies Anywhere API](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/google/moviesanywhere.googleapis.com?pli=1) which you can enable for an Android app. For a web app you are having to rely on deep links.

Unfortunately Google has not published deep link information for the Play Movies app but you can try to take a guess at the URL's to use. For example Google Play uses the prefix "market"

```
<a href="market://details?id=foo.bar" target="_top">Foo Bar</a>
```

would be equivalent to

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=foo.bar
```

So we can take some guesses from that - perhaps it uses the movies prefix, or if you are happy to open the movie from the Play app, perhaps the movies endpoint:

```
movies://details?id=foo.bar    
market://movie?id=foo.bar
```

*As I've emphasised this takes more trial and error (guesswork) so if you get it working please let us know your solution*

Comment: I can get it to open in the Play Store pretty well.  I was able to figure out how to get  the right URL path.  The problem is, a lot of the movies are Movies Anywere and those ones don't show up in the play store as purchased.    If you open it in the Google Movies and TV app, it does show as purchased.

Comment: Ah that's really rubbish that it does not sync the purchases between the two. Were you able to guess the urls to the movies app directly yet?

Comment: Not yet, but I think it has to do with Intents.  The movie ID is the same on youtube and google play, so I would think it is the same.  They also have a link to google play movies in the play store (when viewing a video), so if I can figure out how to get something like <a href="intent://open?id=IkrfpsjTJzo#Intent;package=com.google.android.videos;"> working, then I should be good.  I tried loading the APK into an online tool that opens it, but I don't know enough about android to figure out how that link works.

Comment: If you have the APK look in the AndroidManifest.xml for an <intent-filter> with "scheme" in there

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find way to open some particular movie in Play movies.
I don't think that's easily possible.
You'll have to do it with play store only.

You'll have to use Intent like this:

```
String movieName = "freedom";

// to open in market without browser.
String movieUri = "market://search?c=movies&q="+movieName; 

// to option include browser too.
String movieUri = "https://play.google.com/store/search?c=movies&q="+movieName;
Intent openMovie = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(movieUri));

startActivity(openMovie);
```

Also if you have the Playmovie id you can open that specific movie like this

```
String movieId = "sGRsXdcZeVo";
String movieUri = "https://play.google.com/store/movies/details?id="+movieId;
Intent openMovie = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(movieUri));

startActivity(openMovie);
```

If you just want to open Play movies you can open with

```
Intent openMovie = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/movies"));

startActivity(openMovie);
```

If you want to open play movies's Library use

```
Intent openMovie = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/movies/movies"));

startActivity(openMovie);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am looking to build a android app that would do this, so this will be helpful.  Right now, I am mostly looking for something that can be done from a website.

Comment: Also I had tried with all combinations to open play movies by myself before, but couldn't succeed to match exact requirement, I posted what most I got by tinkering and other sources.